# Error using glib2 from yum: "libgio-2.0.so.0: undefined symbol: g_free"

Tags: yum, libraries, shared-library, amazon-linux, glib

I am trying to build all of the dependencies for Weasyprint 52.5 for AWS Lambda. Despite being a python library, Weasyprint has a large number of OS dependencies.

I'm creating a lambda layer by downloading all of the necessary rpms from yum and extracting the shared libraries. It nearly works but I can't seem to get around this error with libgio.

The OS is Amazon Linux 2, which uses yum for package management and seems to match up with CentOS 7.

This is the yum call command:

```
yumdownloader libffi pixman freetype fontconfig libglvnd libglvnd-glx libglvnd-egl mesa-libglapi libpng libxcb libXrender libX11 libXext libXau libXdamage libXfixes libXxf86vm expat libuuid libxshmfence libdrm libwayland-client libwayland-server glib2 fribidi libthai harfbuzz graphite2 gdk-pixbuf2 cairo pango
```

Which pulls these package versions:

```
cairo-1.15.12-4.amzn2.x86_64
expat-2.1.0-12.amzn2.x86_64
fontconfig-2.13.0-4.3.amzn2.x86_64
freetype-2.8-14.amzn2.1.x86_64
fribidi-1.0.2-1.amzn2.1.x86_64
gdk-pixbuf2-2.36.12-3.amzn2.x86_64
glib2-2.56.1-9.amzn2.0.1.x86_64
graphite2-1.3.10-1.amzn2.0.2.x86_64
harfbuzz-1.7.5-2.amzn2.x86_64
libdrm-2.4.97-2.amzn2.x86_64
libffi-3.0.13-18.amzn2.0.2.x86_64
libglvnd-1.0.1-0.1.git5baa1e5.amzn2.0.1.x86_64
libglvnd-egl-1.0.1-0.1.git5baa1e5.amzn2.0.1.x86_64
libglvnd-glx-1.0.1-0.1.git5baa1e5.amzn2.0.1.x86_64
libpng-1.5.13-8.amzn2.x86_64
libthai-0.1.14-9.amzn2.0.2.x86_64
libuuid-2.30.2-2.amzn2.0.4.x86_64
libwayland-client-1.17.0-1.amzn2.x86_64
libwayland-server-1.17.0-1.amzn2.x86_64
libX11-1.6.7-3.amzn2.0.2.x86_64
libXau-1.0.8-2.1.amzn2.0.2.x86_64
libxcb-1.12-1.amzn2.0.2.x86_64
libXdamage-1.1.4-4.1.amzn2.0.2.x86_64
libXext-1.3.3-3.amzn2.0.2.x86_64
libXfixes-5.0.3-1.amzn2.0.2.x86_64
libXrender-0.9.10-1.amzn2.0.2.x86_64
libxshmfence-1.2-1.amzn2.0.2.x86_64
libXxf86vm-1.1.4-1.amzn2.0.2.x86_64
mesa-libglapi-18.3.4-5.amzn2.0.1.x86_64
pango-1.42.4-4.amzn2.x86_64
pixman-0.34.0-1.amzn2.0.2.x86_64
```

Running rpmdev-extract to extract the rpms results in these shared libraries:

```
libcairo-script-interpreter.so.2.11512.0
libcairo.so.2.11512.0
libdrm_amdgpu.so.1.0.0
libdrm_intel.so.1.0.0
libdrm_nouveau.so.2.0.0
libdrm_radeon.so.1.0.1
libdrm.so.2.4.0
libEGL.so.1.1.0
libexpat.so.1.6.0
libffi.so.6.0.1
libfontconfig.so.1.11.1
libfreetype.so.6.14.0
libfribidi.so.0.4.0
libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0.3612.0
libgdk_pixbuf_xlib-2.0.so.0.3612.0
libgio-2.0.so.0.5600.1
libglapi.so.0.0.0
libGLdispatch.so.0.0.0
libglib-2.0.so.0.5600.1
libGL.so.1.7.0
libGLX.so.0.0.0
libgmodule-2.0.so.0.5600.1
libgobject-2.0.so.0.5600.1
libgraphite2.so.3.0.1
libgthread-2.0.so.0.5600.1
libharfbuzz.so.0.10705.0
libkms.so.1.0.0
libpango-1.0.so.0.4200.3
libpangocairo-1.0.so.0.4200.3
libpangoft2-1.0.so.0.4200.3
libpangoxft-1.0.so.0.4200.3
libpixman-1.so.0.34.0
libpng15.so.15
libpng15.so.15.13.0
libthai.so.0.1.6
libuuid.so.1.3.0
libwayland-client.so.0.3.0
libwayland-server.so.0.1.0
libX11.so.6.3.0
libX11-xcb.so.1.0.0
libXau.so.6.0.0
libxcb-composite.so.0.0.0
libxcb-damage.so.0.0.0
libxcb-dpms.so.0.0.0
libxcb-dri2.so.0.0.0
libxcb-dri3.so.0.0.0
libxcb-glx.so.0.0.0
libxcb-present.so.0.0.0
libxcb-randr.so.0.1.0
libxcb-record.so.0.0.0
libxcb-render.so.0.0.0
libxcb-res.so.0.0.0
libxcb-screensaver.so.0.0.0
libxcb-shape.so.0.0.0
libxcb-shm.so.0.0.0
libxcb.so.1.1.0
libxcb-sync.so.1.0.0
libxcb-xevie.so.0.0.0
libxcb-xf86dri.so.0.0.0
libxcb-xfixes.so.0.0.0
libxcb-xinerama.so.0.0.0
libxcb-xinput.so.0.1.0
libxcb-xkb.so.1.0.0
libxcb-xselinux.so.0.0.0
libxcb-xtest.so.0.0.0
libxcb-xvmc.so.0.0.0
libxcb-xv.so.0.0.0
libXdamage.so.1.1.0
libXext.so.6.4.0
libXfixes.so.3.1.0
libXrender.so.1.3.0
libxshmfence.so.1.0.0
libXxf86vm.so.1.0.0
```

When Weasyprint calls `ffi.dlopen("libfontconfig.so.1")`, I get an OSError:

> cannot load library 'libfontconfig.so.1': /opt/lib/libgio-2.0.so.0:
> undefined symbol: g_free

I have tried downgrading some of the key packages to the other versions available on yum, but with no success. Specifically, I have tried downgrading the following:

```
fontconfig-2.10.95
glib2-2.50.3
cairo-1.14.8
pango-1.40.4
```

but this results in the same error.

What is causing the undefined symbol error? Is there any workaround that will resolve this error?

---

**UPDATE**

I'm now wondering if this is related to AWS Lambda specifically.

I am building the dependencies on an Amazon2 Docker instance however I cannot replicate the problem in my Docker container. For example, here is my current Dockerfile, run on an Amazon2 EC2 instance:

https://pastebin.com/Kd65URru

Note that this Dockerfile uses a slightly modified version of Weasyprint 52.5 where I've added some extra error logging. I also added some code to force ffi to load libraries specifically from /opt/lib:

https://github.com/Kozea/WeasyPrint/compare/v52.5...MasonryHQ:temp?expand=1

When I build this Docker container, I encounter no errors. However when I zip up my `/opt/lib` directory and upload it to Lambda as a layer, I still get the error on Lambda as soon as I try to import Weasyprint. See:

https://sentry.io/share/issue/1d2d824e950346e9bcc368f8abfd01f0/

Is it possible some libraries in Docker are still not loading from /opt/lib despite my changes to Weasyprint? Or is Lambda just behaving differently than the Docker container?

Comment: "Weasyprint-52.5 dependencies" https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/17U4LkT6ZNiyYuWh2Zo5qoUs4BBR2Sulu?usp=sharing .... and CentOS 7 build : The missing python3 modules are automatically downloaded, and installed → CentOS7__python3_setup.py_install.txt

Comment: @KnudLarsen I see the python deps, but those are ok. The rpm packages have the conflict.

There's a Fedora rpm of Weasyprint in that GDrive folder. I tried yum-builddep on that rpm as suggested. I just got those deps with `yumdownloader --resolve`, but on importing Weasyprint, I got the OSError `libexpat.so.1: cannot open shared object file`

I added expat (and libuuid after a similar error). Then I got the error `gobject-2.0: cannot open shared object file`

I had to install glib2 to get gobject. Now I'm back to the original error: `libgio-2.0.so.0: undefined symbol: g_free`. Any ideas?

Comment: 1. Isn't there currently any glib2 files in /usr/lib64 which can conflict ? ........ 2. Default el7 is `glib2-2.56.1-9.el7_9.x86_64` → {`libglib-2.0.so.0.5600.1, libgio-2.0.so.0.5600.1`}. The files in /opt/ must all have same consistency / same update level. ..... 3. We are missing *a reproducible example command*  in your question, to test Weasyprint. ...... (4. The fedora package is just an example of version 52.5. Not a recommendation to use any Fedora 34 files.)

Comment: Found "samples/" https://github.com/Kozea/WeasyPrint/tree/gh-pages → Download zip. .... `$ cd WeasyPrint-gh-pages/samples/ && ./gen.sh` : No libgio error with a default CentOS 7 install. I.e. /usr/lib64/glib-2.0 files are used.

Comment: @KnudLarsen The default el7 versions are the versions being used here aside from my unsuccessful attempts to downgrade a few of them as mentioned in the question.

See the update I just added to the question where I tried to replicate the problem in Docker directly. The problem seems to only be happening in the lambda layer as indicated in the Sentry stack trace I posted. Any idea why?

Comment: It's not actually a command. The error happens as soon as you `import weasyprint` into python as you can see in the Sentry.io stack trace. But yeah, it only seems to happen on Lambda. I tried to make my Docker an exact match for Lambda but it works there. So I'm not sure how you can replicate it :(

Comment: CentOS 7 : `$ python3` <Enter> `>>> import weasyprint` <Enter> `>>>` ..... I.e. no errors.